# Storing items into local storage seems to not working

Tags: javascript

Im making todo app for myself. And trying to save the data inside the local storage. I just want to ask about my code if iam doing something wrong.

```
my html :
```

```
    <div id="todo1">
        <center><h1>All Tasks</h1></center>
        <div id="todo"></div>
        <form class="add-items">
            <center><input type="text" name="item" placeholder="eg. Buy bread" class="add_task" required></center>
        <center><input type="submit" class="add" value="add task"/></center>
        </form>

    </div>
```

```
my javascript:
```

```
    const addItems = document.querySelector('.add-items'); 
    const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];

    function addItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let todo = document.querySelector('#todo');
        let input = (this.querySelector('[name=item]').value);
        let text = document.createTextNode(input);
        let markup = `<center><div class="task">${input}<i class="far fa-check-circle"></i><i class="far fa-trash-alt" id="trash"></i></div></center>`;
        todo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
        const item = {
            task:input
        };
        items.push(item);
        localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
        this.reset();
    }

    addItems.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
```

Comment: I had gone through your code its successfully storing data into local storage the only thing i can suggest you is that please give an id to your todo item its super efficient when you will try to remove items, manipulate or work with large data/applications.

Comment: i know it its storing but when i refresh the page the inserted html on page is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the Items that you stored into localStorage are not binded to the html dom initially that's why you are unable to see your items from localStorage in the view.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/r76xots2/9/]
```

So here is the working link for your code with some optimization where I have created a common function that will update your dom from the localStorage which can be used every time whenever you want to update.

I have also created a check so the same item can't be inserted twice. If you don't require that, you could remove or comment it.

Comment: I found a solution lately a refractored my code. But thanks anyway

Comment: @codeHysteria - if you want to say "Thanks", please upvote Senthur's answer above. We are a community and we need to thank each other meaningfully. Thank you.

Comment: @codeHysteria Please do an upvote if my answers were helpful which will encourage new contributors like me to share knowledge and answer more questions